# Make a stage happen in gitlab-ci if one of two other stages completed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, terraform, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline that runs automatically when code is pushed to gitlab. There's a terraform apply step that I want to be able to run manually in one case (resources destroyed/recreated) and automatically in another (resources simply added or destroyed.) I almost got this with a manual step but can't see how to get the pipeline to be automatic in the safe case. The manual terraform apply step would not be the last in the pipeline.

Is it possible to say 'do step C if step A completed or step B completed'? Kind of branch the pipeline? Or could I do it with two pipelines, and failure in one triggers the other?

Current partial test code (gitlab CI yaml) here:

```
# stop with a warning if resources will be created and destroyed 
check:
  stage: check
  script:
    - ./terraformCheck.sh
  allow_failure: true

# Apply changes manually, whether there is a warning or not
override:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - ./terraformApply.sh
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  only:
    - master

log:
  stage: log
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - ./terraformLog.sh

  when: always
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Why not have the check job just apply if it's safe and then have a redundant manual apply job that has an empty apply in that case or actually does stuff if it wasn't safe?

Comment: Thank you, I did try that, but then either you make the manual apply blocking so you have to do it manually anyway, or you make it non blocking and the rest of the pipeline carries on without it. We'd like to only intervene with a manual step if we have to, and allow us to check we are happy and then carry on. Unless I misunderstood how it works?